# Toolbar badge count is not working when I tried to set it programmatically from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have made dependency services on both side and Interface in shared library on Xamarin platform
when i use it in xaml.cs hard coded it works but when i use it in ViewModel using messaging center to set count of notification in Toolbar of application it doesn't works 
Does anyone have any kind of idea whats happening or should i do ?

this code works from Xaml.cs page

```
DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>().SetBadge(this, ToolbarItems[0], "2", Color.Red, Color.White);
```

And Below Code doesn't works

```
From ViewModel 
" MessagingCenter.Send(new MessagingCenterModel { }, "NotificationCount", NotificationListCount);

At Xaml.cs Page
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MessagingCenterModel, string>(this, "NotificationCount", (sender, args) =>
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>().SetBadge(this, ToolbarItems[0], args, Color.Red, Color.White);

            });
```

InterFaceCode

```
public interface IToolbarItemBadgeService
{
    void SetBadge(Page page, ToolbarItem item, string value, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor);
}
```

Dependency service

```
public class ToolbarItemBadgeService : IToolbarItemBadgeService
{
    public void SetBadge(Page page, ToolbarItem item, string value, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            var toolbar = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    var idx = page.ToolbarItems.IndexOf(item);
                    if (toolbar.Menu.Size() > idx)
                    {
                        var menuItem = toolbar.Menu.GetItem(idx);
                        BadgeDrawable.SetBadgeText(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, menuItem, value, backgroundColor.ToAndroid(), textColor.ToAndroid());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BadgeDrawable Class

```
public class BadgeDrawable : Drawable
{
    private const string BadgeValueOverflow = "*";

    private Paint _badgeBackground;
    private Paint _badgeText;
    private Rect _textRect = new Rect();

    private string _badgeValue = "";
    private bool _shouldDraw = true;
    Context _context;

    public override int Opacity => (int)Format.Unknown;

    public BadgeDrawable(Context context, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor)
    {

        _context = context;
        float textSize = context.Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.textsize_badge_count);
        _badgeBackground = new Paint();
        _badgeBackground.Color = backgroundColor;
        _badgeBackground.AntiAlias = true;
        _badgeBackground.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);

        _badgeText = new Paint();
        _badgeText.Color = textColor;
        _badgeText.SetTypeface(Typeface.Default);
        _badgeText.TextSize = textSize;
        _badgeText.AntiAlias = true;
        _badgeText.TextAlign = Paint.Align.Center;
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (!_shouldDraw)
        {
            return;
        }
        Rect bounds = Bounds;
        float width = bounds.Right - bounds.Left;
        float height = bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top;
        float oneDp = 1 * _context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

        // Position the badge in the top-right quadrant of the icon.
        float radius = ((Java.Lang.Math.Max(width, height) / 2)) / 2;
        float centerX = (width - radius - 1) + oneDp * 2;
        float centerY = radius - 2 * oneDp;
        canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius + oneDp * 5), _badgeBackground);

        // Draw badge count message inside the circle.
        _badgeText.GetTextBounds(_badgeValue, 0, _badgeValue.Length, _textRect);
        float textHeight = _textRect.Bottom - _textRect.Top;
        float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
        canvas.DrawText(_badgeValue.Length > 2 ? BadgeValueOverflow : _badgeValue,
                centerX, textY, _badgeText);
    }

    // Sets the text to display. Badge displays a '*' if more than 2 characters
    private void SetBadgeText(string text)
    {
        _badgeValue = text;

        // Only draw a badge if the value isn't a zero
        _shouldDraw = !text.Equals("0");
        InvalidateSelf();
    }

    public override void SetAlpha(int alpha)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public override void SetColorFilter(ColorFilter cf)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    public static void SetBadgeCount(Context context, IMenuItem item, int count, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor)
    {
        SetBadgeText(context, item, $"{count}", backgroundColor, textColor);
    }

    public static void SetBadgeText(Context context, IMenuItem item, string text, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor)
    {


        if (item.Icon == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        BadgeDrawable badge = null;
        Drawable icon = item.Icon;


        if (item.Icon is LayerDrawable)
        {

            LayerDrawable lDrawable = item.Icon as LayerDrawable;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text == "0")
            {
                icon = lDrawable.GetDrawable(0);
                lDrawable.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < lDrawable.NumberOfLayers; i++)
                {
                    if (lDrawable.GetDrawable(i) is BadgeDrawable)
                    {
                        badge = lDrawable.GetDrawable(i) as BadgeDrawable;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if (badge == null)
                {
                    badge = new BadgeDrawable(context, backgroundColor, textColor);
                    icon = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { item.Icon, badge });
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            badge = new BadgeDrawable(context, backgroundColor, textColor);
            icon = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { item.Icon, badge });
        }

        badge?.SetBadgeText(text);

        item.SetIcon(icon);
        icon.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the line `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` been invoked ?

Comment: yes @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: i am giving you the link that i have followed while coding it
https://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/08/adding-badge-to-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/  
Just i have done it with MVVM pattern
@LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Where did you send the message , the constructor or other?

Comment: It works fine on my side . `MessagingCenter.Send<MessagingCenterModel, string>(this, "NotificationCount", NotificationListCount);`

Comment: In other Function which is called at On Appearing override mothod @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205187/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sufiyan-patel).

Comment: Now I have posted it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , make sure that we had `Subscribe` the message before we send it . Otherwise the codes in  Subscribe will never been called .

In addition , the code in **Dependency Service** could only set the badge of `ToolbarItem` in the navigation bar (on tabbed bar it will never work).

If you want to set the badge of tabbed page icon , you could use the plugin [Plugin.Badge](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge) .